# Include View In Node That References Other Nodes Based On Joined Field

Tags: views, nodes

I'm getting a little confused trying to get this one, thought I'd get some help.

I have two content types (`A` and `B`) both with the same list field (`My List`). I want to include a view in content type `A` that finds all nodes of content type `B` with the same `My List` value.

I've looked through Context, Entity Reference (which I didn't really get) and Views Relationships and Contexts but couldn't make much sense of it.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

### **Edit:**

I've added an image of my desired output (from actual site) and the current fields of content type's `A` and `B`.

An important note is that the Views block/whatever showing content type `B` needs to be shown in the **normal node page** of content type `A`.

**I know this isn't the best way to do this, but this feature wasn't planned and the client just wants it to work as fast as possible**

### **Content Types Fields:**

*I've excluded irrelevant fields such as path and meta tags.*

**Content type A:**

```
Title - text
Body - HTML (w/ text inside)
Department - List
```

**Content type B:**

```
Title (name) - text
Description - text
Department - List
```

### **Desired Output:**

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: What is for you a view in content type A? and can you provide a Image of your desire output?

Comment: Yes, I'll add it right now.

Comment: You can achieve this with my answer, takes a look and let me know the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a View to show nodes of Content Type `B`, add a Contextual Filter for your field `My List` and save the view.

Install the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module and then in the ***Footer*** region of your View of Content Type `A` add the  `Global: View (Views field view)` and configure under the ***View settings*** the ***Name*** and ***Display*** of your B View and the token for the ***Contextual filters***.

To use the value of the `My List` field as a token, you must have in the ***Fields*** of your view this field selected.

**Edit** after your comment ("*I'd prefer to keep using the regular node page.*")

You can use the [EVA module](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva), it provides a Views display plugin that allows the output of a View to be attached to the content of any Drupal entity, in your case the node of Type A. In the contextual filter of the view you need select the `My List` field in the ***Entity Content Settings*** of the View using a token.

"[Entity Views Attach: Use Views Almost Anywhere](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/entity-views-attach/)" contains a great tutorial about it.

Comment: Content type `A` isn't shown using a view, and I'd prefer to keep using the regular node page.

Comment: @neta give a minute

Comment: @Neta sorry for the delay, I edit with the oter option ;-)

Comment: Thanks! That was extremely helpful and exactly the way I wanted it to be!
Add to your answer that I also needed to add an argument to `My List` field in the **Entity Content Settings** in the view using a token.